# Were there serious a priori fictional languages before Tolkien?

Tags: history, list-of-languages, artlangs

By serious I mean somewhat complete, with a working grammar. So the examples in Gulliver's Travels are probably not really "languages" (or are they, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 4):

[Baleybelen (~14c?)](https://catalog.princeton.edu/catalog/9951681003506421) is often considered as the oldest well-documented a priori conlang. Much older than Solresol (1827). Unfortunately, I know no Turkish so I can't really tell what the content. The [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balaibalan) say that, akin to Lingua Ignota, Baleybelen is thought to be a religion-motivated or language for poetry (maybe related to Sufism?). But unlike Lingua Ignota which borrowed most of its structure and vocabulary from Latin, Baleybelen is thought to be an a priori language.